# __iter__ and __next__ on vector class is doing some weird stuff

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, iterator, iterable

I have a vector class that I've been building

```py
# vector.py
class Vector(object):
    def __init__(self, vec:list):
        self._vector = vec
        self._size   = len(vec)

    def __iter__(self):
        self._index = 0
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        if self._index < self._size:
            self._index += 1
            return self._index-1
        else:
            raise StopIteration
```

Theres a lot more code than this and I have also implemented a `__getitem__` dunder function as well.
I was playing around in a test file and wanted to do a sum of the vector without using the python `sum()` function.

```py
from functools import reduce
import vector

vec = vector.Vector([1, 2, 3, -4])
print(reduce(lambda x,y: x+y, vec))

# I would expect 2 to be returned but got 6 instead.
# So I tried something else instead

print(reduce(lambda x,y: x+y, [1, 2, 3, -4]))
# This returns 2 like expected.
```

So I don't know why it works when I pass reduce() a python list and not the vector class. I guess it's something to do with how I've implemented `__iter__` and `__next__`.  What do you guys think?

Comment: You should be returning the value in you `__next__` method, not the index.

Comment: Your vector shouldn't be its own iterator anyway. It should be iterable, but not an iterator. Making it its own iterator prevents nested loops over the same vector, as well as preventing thread-safe or reentrant loops.

Comment: The standard library [`collections.abc`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html) simplifies this greatly for you. All you do is provide `__getitem__` and `__len__`, and inherit your class from `collections.abc.Sequence`, and you get a working iterator implementation - plus reverse iterators, an implementation for the `in` operator, and `.index` and `.count` methods the same as lists provide.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Thanks although I'm getting a AttributeError: module 'collections' has no attribute 'abc' error. Any idea what's going on?

Comment: Because of how Python's module/package system works, you need to actually `import collections.abc`; you can't just `import collections` and then expect `collections.abc` to be defined.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Thanks. I've never really used collections or abc before. I've seen them but never used them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your implementation of `__next__`, you're returning the index instead of the *element*. `[0, 1, 2, 3]` was being generated, which sums to 6.

Fix:

```
    def __iter__(self):
        self._index = 0
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        if self._index < self._size:
            self._index += 1
            return self._vec[self._index-1]
            #      ^^^^^^^^^^             ^
        else:
            raise StopIteration
```

Comment: Thanks. From the tutorials I read about __next__ they all return the index value instead of the element.

Comment: @Aguy: Either you misread them, or you're reading bad tutorials.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Probably a bit of both to be honest